# Full size background image for col-*-* in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, col

i already found some questions regarding this topic but none of them could really help me solving my problem.

I like to build a simple Bootstrap grid looking like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8"> Some Text </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="..." alt="Full Size Background Image" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="..." alt="Full Size Background Image" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8"> Some Text </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The col-sm-4-DIVs should contain a full size background image with the same height as the text and no padding.

Here's a photo of what I mean. I want the background image to cover the red area:

[See Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcQYp.jpg)

Any ideas how to do that?

Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First option**, you can set `min-width:100%` in your `img` tag:

```
img {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

**Or Second option**, you can set the image as a background and set it in the div that you want:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 full-img">
```

And the css:

```
.full-img {
    background-image: url("....");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately the image doesn't cover the whole column and i still have a padding on all sides. I attached a photo of what I mean to my main post.

Answer (score 0):

use css to set the background image on the column

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-image:url('.....')">
      content......
     </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately the image doesn't cover the whole column and i still have a padding on all sides. I attached a photo of what I mean to my main post.

Comment: try setting a negative margin on the image... something like: style="margin-left:-15px;"